# Платежная система и запись в БД?

Tags: php, october, octobercms

Использую Октябрь. Создана страница заказа, где собирается вся информация. Начал привязывать платежную систему. Для ее использования, нужно отправить POST запрос с суммой на их сервер.
Вопрос: как одновременно, на одной странице реализовать и запись необходимых данных в БД и перенаправить после этого на платежную систему?
Как я понял по примерам, в октябре при обработке форм используется исключительно AJAX, как из onOrder() - AJAX функции перенаправит на платежную систему?
P.S method="POST" action="..." работают, но тогда нельзя записать данные в БД

Comment: Всё просто. Вы через ajax отправляете запрос на свой сервер. Там скрипт отправляет запрос на сервер платёжной системы. Результат пишет в базу и возвращает ответ c адресом перенаправления в форме json. На стороне клиента вам остаётся сделать перенаправление на адрес, пришедший с сервера.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сделать)